# Primeng custom template access over a specific item

Tags: angular, primeng

I have created a sample primeng dropdown with custom template. Now i want to access a specific element from the dropdown. 
Like i will do some styling on that particular list element from css. 
Dropdown each items class is ui-dropdown-item. So i tried like adding a wrapper div with condition and nested css with .ui-dropdown-item, which is not working.

```js
import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/api';

export class MyModel {

    cars: SelectItem[]; //extended SelectItem Interface to add disabled property

    selectedCar: string;

    constructor() {
        this.cars = [
            {label: 'Audi', value: 'Audi',disabled:true},
            {label: 'BMW', value: 'BMW'},
            {label: 'Fiat', value: 'Fiat'},
            {label: 'Ford', value: 'Ford'},
            {label: 'Honda', value: 'Honda'},
            {label: 'Jaguar', value: 'Jaguar'},
            {label: 'Mercedes', value: 'Mercedes'},
            {label: 'Renault', value: 'Renault'},
            {label: 'VW', value: 'VW'},
            {label: 'Volvo', value: 'Volvo'},
        ];
    }
}
```

```css
.disabled{
  .ui-dropdown-item{
    color: #aaa,
    cursor: default,
    pointer-event: none
  }
}
```

```html
<p-dropdown [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCar" [style]="{'width':'150px'}">
     <ng-template let-item pTemplate="selectedItem"> 
        <img src="assets/showcase/images/demo/car/{{item.label}}.png" /> 
        <span>{{item.label}}</span>
    </ng-template> 
    <ng-template let-car pTemplate="item"> 
        <div [ngClass]="item.disabled === true ? 'disabled' : '' ">
        <img src="assets/showcase/images/demo/car/{{car.label}}.png" /> 
        <div>{{car.label}}</div> </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is good but you made a few mistakes.

**CSS**

- Remove nested class `ui-dropdown-item`
- CSS property should finish by *;* instead of *,*

So

```
.disabled{
  .ui-dropdown-item{
    color: #aaa,
    cursor: default,
    pointer-event: none
  }
}
```

becomes

```
.disabled{
    color: #aaa;
    cursor: default;
    pointer-event: none;
}
```

**HTML**

- `disabled` property should be applied to `car` instead of `item`

So

```
<div [ngClass]="item.disabled === true ? 'disabled' : '' ">
```

becomes

```
<div [ngClass]="car.disabled === true ? 'disabled' : '' ">
```

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/B4OdH3NU6jxLWJu9fMDm?p=preview)